# Retrieve a model from another view when calling as component

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently trying to call a component from another application, I have created a button in my app and when they click the button it loads the popover how I want it to. But now they want their own button which will open the popover. So what I thought would work is at the start of my controller add this:

```
_view: null,
```

then onInit add this.

```
this._view = this.getView();
```

Then later on when I want to reference this view I thought I could just use this_view and it would work. It still works fine with these changes for my button, but for there button it is setting this._view back to null.

So what I'm actually trying to do is get a model from the view like this:

```
this._view.getModel("modelName");
```

but it throws an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getModel' of null. As this._view is null. Is there anyway to make the view global for when another application calls the component. Or is there a way to use like sap.ui.getCore. I have tried looking in to this but I keep coming up a blank.

Again when they use the button I created it works, I assume as this is part of the apps view, so this is only an issue when they call it from there applications button.

TIA

Comment: What is "their own button"?

Comment: kind of unclear description, do you mind creating a jsbin example?